# Getting Twitter user details using swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform, pfuser

I have been searching since few days on how I can get user details based on his/her Twitter account ,I'm using twitter login in my application 
& I haven't found anything about this in Swift, so i'm asking! 
How can I get the username & email & uprofile Image of a logged in User with Parse from Twitter in order to save them on parse cloud?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the username and userID of the logged-in user pretty easily. Inside most Twitter login methods you'll see something like this:

```
@IBAction func loginTwitter(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion {
        (session, error) -> Void in
        if (session != nil) {

            print(session?.userName)
            print(session?.userID)
        } else {
            print("error")

        }
    }
}
```

Twitter does not expose the email address of users as far as I'm aware.

For the profile image you'll need to send a GET request. Here is some code that may not be up to date with the latest TwitterKit version but should at least give you a sense of how the request should be formatted.

```
func getUserInfo(screenName : String){
    if let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()!.userID {
        let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)
        let url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"
        let params = ["screen_name": screenName]
        var clientError : NSError?
        let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: url, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if let someData = data {
                do {
                    let results = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(someData, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    print(results)

                } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to go through the JSON that gets returned and find "profile_image_url_https" a couple levels down.

Good Luck!

Comment: how to find screen name??

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

It's getting email also.

```
import TwitterKit 


@IBAction func onClickTwitterSignin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in
        if (session != nil) {
            let name = session?.userName ?? ""
            print(name)
            print(session?.userID  ?? "")
            print(session?.authToken  ?? "")
            print(session?.authTokenSecret  ?? "")
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
            client.requestEmail { email, error in
                if (email != nil) {
                    let recivedEmailID = email ?? ""
                    print(recivedEmailID)
                }else {
                    print("error--: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
                }
            }

        //To get profile image url and screen name
        let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userID)
            twitterClient.loadUser(withID: session?.userID ?? "") {(user, error) in
            print(user?.profileImageURL ?? "")
            print(user?.profileImageLargeURL ?? "")
            print(user?.screenName ?? "")
        }

            let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storyboard, animated: true)
        }else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
        }
    }
}
```

For logout

```
@IBAction func onClickTwitterSignout(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let store = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore
    if let userID = store.session()?.userID {
        print(store.session()?.userID ?? "")
        store.logOutUserID(userID)
        print(store.session()?.userID ?? "")
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```